# Is the lack of a [homework] tag purposeful?

Tags: discussion, tags

As a user who's spent most of my time over on stackoverflow, I'm very familiar with the concept of homework questions being asked on stack exchange sites.  For a while there was a vicious commenting/downvote pattern going on, and ultimately [homework] questions were tagged as such, and users could titrate information in the answers to match the appropriate guidance for homework problems.

Today I saw [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/is-it-possible-that-the-last-piece-the-ant-has-eaten-is-the-central-one), and after the OP confirmed that it is homework, I went to tag it as such.  I discovered that there is no such tag in existence right now!  A bit of searching turned up [a meta discussion about whether homework should be allowed](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/should-homework-be-allowed), but nothing about a [homework] tag came up.

So... I don't feel like I have enough of a presence in the community to be adding tags at this point.  However, from my stackoverflow experience, a [homework] tag can be quite useful.  I would propose creating such a tag, even if homework questions are few and far between, in the hopes that it can serve a similar purpose here.  Thoughts from the community?

Comment: How exactly do you believe it will benefit the community?

Comment: (IMHO) It barely comes up often enough to warrant policy, let alone a whole tag...

Comment: As Gareth answered it there, he just gave a hint to OP and requested others to not answer it right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

<sup>(Or should it be rather *yes*, the *lack* of the tag is purposeful?)</sup>

I don't think a homework tag would be helpful. As Alconja pointed out in the comments, "puzzle homeworks" are rare cases (-and mathematical questions are off-topic anyway-) and if they are, they are more often "for the pupil's fun sake" than serious - so if somebody decided to *look up* (or *request*) the answer, it's his/her choice to make.

Besides, it *would* be a meta-tag and there is nothing "special" about it which would be a valid argument for *this* type of meta-tag as opposed to the general discussion.
Would you want to search/find puzzles *particularly* because they are 'homework'?

And the purpose of stating "Hey, I got this for homework, only give hints" is much better served by the post actually saying this than a tag.

Comment: This sounds good to me.  I'm glad I asked instead of creating an unnecessary tag.