# Questions from homework/assigments

Tags: discussion, questions

This question: [Encrypted message (unknown algorithm or plaintext)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/56746/encrypted-message-unknown-algorithm-or-plaintext) raised, or rather, revived a doubt in my mind.

We do have a clear policy on the [questions from on-going contests](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests) but what about homework questions?

- Is it ethically right to solve it for others?
- Do we need similar policies as that on [Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)?

---

Comment: See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/should-homework-be-allowed where there's quite a bit about this.

Comment: I think this should be closed as a duplicate of the question @GarethMcCaughan pointed out, if only so we don't have people sharing their opinions in two places.  At minimum, if the present question remains open and you see fit to answer it or vote on it or its answers, I strongly encourage you to look at the earlier question and vote for the answer(s) there that you agree with, if any.

Comment: @Rubio Yes, thanks for that. I am having a look at that question and its answers.

Answer (score 4):

### Absolutely not; we should not do other's homework

Homework and assignments count for grades in some countries. Answering these would be analogous to sitting their exam for them. Even if homework is not being marked, it is still wrong to solve it for them as the teacher set the homework for **them** to do, and to learn from. Furthermore, typical 'homework' style questions are most likely off-topic here on puzzling, at least in my experience.